# Message from Jupyter "Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages."

Tags: anaconda, jupyter, openvino

Running "%pip show openvino" in Jupyter notebook, besides normal information, there is a  Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.

I have installed OpenVINO in Anaconda.Nevigator. When I tried to run "%pip show openvino" in Jupyter notebook, the output is:
Name: openvino
Version: 2024.0.0
Summary: OpenVINO(TM) Runtime
Home-page: https://docs.openvino.ai/2023.0/index.html
Author: Intel(R) Corporation
Author-email: openvino@intel.com
License: OSI Approved :: Apache Software License
Location: D:\Anaconda\envs\myEnvironment\Lib\site-packages
Requires: numpy, openvino-telemetry, packaging
Required-by:
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
It seems something wrong. I restarted the kernel and tried again. Nothing changed.

Comment: Sometimes restarting the kernel alone isn't sufficient. You should in those cases start with refreshing the browser page. You may want to shut down Jupyter and the browser, and even restart the computer completely. Sometimes for very complex installs there are settings that need to be propagated. Sometimes a kernel restart or that and a browser page refresh are sufficient; however, not always. It may be better to think of that notice to restart the kernel is the minimal thing to try.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind though is that page you linked to is marked as outdated. Are you sure this has been updated? It may not work for a reason out of your control. What are you doing to test if anything changed? Usually you just run the import and make sure it works. For things with display changes, that doesn't fully test things. So I'm curious what you are trying here and not seeing what you expect? In other words, "...and tried again" and "Nothing changed" don't tell us much of anything.

Answer (score 0):

Run the command below to verify the OpenVINO™ package is installed in the environment:

```
from openvino import Core
print(Core().available_devices)
```

If the installation is successful, the list of available devices will be printed.